# Repeating a vue function

Tags: jquery, search, filter, vuejs2, repeat

I would like to know how to repeat the following, but do not know how. I have multiple lists on my page and would like a search function above those lists. I can make one list working, but what if I do not know how many lists can be there? In Jquery I would use a .each(). How can I with Vue, look at the lists in the dom, find a jason array from each of those lists and add a search?

I added a fiddle with an example:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmfm2wk6/1/)

```
<script>
window.result = [
            {
                "title": "What You Need To Know About CSS Variables",
            },
            {
                "title": "Freebie: 4 Great Looking Pricing Tables",
            },
            {
                "title": "20 Interesting JavaScript and CSS Libraries for February 2016",
            },
            {
                "title": "Quick Tip: The Easiest Way To Make Responsive Headers",
            },
            {
                "title": "Learn SQL In 20 Minutes",
            },
            {
                "title": "Creating Your First Desktop App With HTML, JS and Electron",
            }
        ];
        </script>

<form id="main" v-cloak>

    <div class="bar">
        <!-- Create a binding between the searchString model and the text field -->

        <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
    </div>

    <ul>
        <!-- Render a li element for every entry in the computed filteredArticles array. -->

        <li v-for="article in filteredArticles">
            <p>{{article.title}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>

<script>
window.result(2) = [
            {
                "title": "What You Need To Know About CSS Variables",
            }
        ];
        </script>
<form id="main2">

    <div class="bar">
        <!-- Create a binding between the searchString model and the text field -->

        <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
    </div>

    <ul>
        <!-- Render a li element for every entry in the computed filteredArticles array. -->

        <li v-for="article in filteredArticles">
            <p>{{article.title}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>

<script>
window.result(3) = [
            {
                "title": "What You Need To Know About CSS Variables",
            }
        ];
        </script>
<form id="main3">

    <div class="bar">
        <!-- Create a binding between the searchString model and the text field -->

        <input type="text" v-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
    </div>

    <ul>
        <!-- Render a li element for every entry in the computed filteredArticles array. -->

        <li v-for="article in filteredArticles">
            <p>{{article.title}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>

var results =  window.result;

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        searchString: "",
        articles:results
    },
    computed: {
        // A computed property that holds only those articles that match the searchString.
        filteredArticles: function () {
            var articles_array = this.articles,
                searchString = this.searchString;

            if(!searchString){
                return articles_array;
            }

            searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

            articles_array = articles_array.filter(function(item){
                if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                    return item;
                }
            })

            return articles_array;;
        }
    }
```

});

Comment: You want a new Vue instance for each target?

Comment: I don't know the best way to do this. Maybe I can put it in a var and call it in a each function? var test = new vue(); ?

Comment: What does `results` look like? How do you know which results go with each Vue?

Comment: I added a fiddle example.